# Retrieving a Filtered array Length in a Specific Situation using React / Redux

Tags: redux, pagination, react-redux

I need some help with a very basic need although I can't find a good solution. In order for my Table pagination to Work I have this method

```
renderList() {

let flowList;

if (this.props.isLoaded && Object.keys(this.props.flows).length > 0) {
  flowList = Object.entries(this.props.flows).sort(this.filterFlowListByColumn())
    .filter(([idx, flow]) => {
      let tree = MOTIVE_TREES.findItem(flow.productId);
      let macroProcess = tree.macroProcesses[flow.macroId];
      let microProcess = macroProcess.microProcesses[flow.microId];
      let detail = microProcess.details[flow.detailId];
      let subPop = detail.subpops ? detail.subpops[flow.subPopId] : '';
      return this.filterFlows(this.state.searchRegex, [flow.name, tree.productName, macroProcess.name, microProcess.name, detail.name, subPop.name ? subPop.name : '-'])
    })
    .map(([idx, flow]) => {
      let tree = MOTIVE_TREES.findItem(flow.productId);
      let macroProcess = tree.macroProcesses[flow.macroId];
      let microProcess = macroProcess.microProcesses[flow.microId];
      let detail = microProcess.details[flow.detailId];
      let subPop = detail.subpops ? detail.subpops[flow.subPopId] : '';
      return (
        <tr key={flow.identifier} >
          <td className='justify'>{flow.name}</td>
          <td className='text-center'>{tree.productName}</td>
          <td className='text-center'>{macroProcess.name}</td>
          <td className='text-center'>{microProcess.name}</td>
          <td className='text-center'>{detail.name}</td>
          <td className='text-center'>{subPop.name ? subPop.name : '-'}</td>
          <td className='text-center'>
            <Button title='Editar este Fluxo' className='listItemEdit fa fa-pencil-square fa-sm' color='link' tag={Link} onClick={() => { this.props.getStateList(flow) }} to={`/${FLOWS}/flowEditor/${idx}`}></Button>
            &nbsp;
        <Button title='Remover este Fluxo' className='listItemRemove fa fa-trash fa-sm' color='link' onClick={() => this.removeFlowConfirmation(idx)}></Button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      )

    })
      if(this.state.flowLength !== flowList.length){

        this.setState({flowLength: flowList.length})
      }
  return flowList.slice(this.state.currentPage * this.state.pageSize - this.state.pageSize, this.state.currentPage * this.state.pageSize);
} else {
}
```

I need to retrieve the flowList length while the user is filtering this array by Typing on a Search Input, the problem is if I do this -

```
 if(this.state.flowLength !== flowList.length){

            this.setState({flowLength: flowList.length})
          }
```

inside the Render method, it works but it's also anti-pattern according to React, I jus't can't figure a way to retrieve this, by using ComponentUpdate methods from react or setting an Action in Redux, could someone help me? Is it possible to achieve this without changing too much this code structure?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to store `flowList.length` in `state` in the first place? You can just use it anytime you want from the variable `flowList`

Comment: Because i have another method that needs this Filtered length value from FlowList in order so my Pagination can work, and I can't access this Let variable anywhere else. If I try calling a method that also sets the state it just gives me the same anti-pattern warning in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find a Solution myself, I've just coded the first filtering part of the Array inside the componentDidUpdate() method and the Result was this:

```
if (this.props.isLoaded && (prevProps.isLoaded !== this.props.isLoaded
  || this.state.inputSearchText !== prevState.inputSearchText
  || this.state.reverseSort !== prevState.reverseSort
  || this.state.columnId !== prevState.columnId)) {
  let flowList = Object.entries(this.props.flows).sort(this.filterFlowListByColumn())
    .filter(([idx, flow]) => {
      let tree = MOTIVE_TREES.findItem(flow.productId);
      let macroProcess = tree.macroProcesses[flow.macroId];
      let microProcess = macroProcess.microProcesses[flow.microId];
      let detail = microProcess.details[flow.detailId];
      let subPop = detail.subpops ? detail.subpops[flow.subPopId] : '';
      return this.filterFlows(this.state.searchRegex, [flow.name, tree.productName, macroProcess.name, microProcess.name, detail.name, subPop.name ? subPop.name : '-'])
    })
  this.setState({ flowList, flowLength: flowList.length });

}
```

For now I'll leave as this, if anyone come up with a better solution I'll be greatful. Thanks.